# Code for DatePicker - Second date must be greater than the first date by 1 day

Tags: shopify

I've been trying to use lots of guides on how to get the pickupdate DatePicker to increase by 1 day from the dropoffdate DatePicker, but I can't get it to work.  I'm unsure how to get the two elements to work together in the `<script>` tags.

What I have is:

```
{{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js' | script_tag }}

<div style="width:300px; clear:both;">
  <p>
    <label for="dropoffdate">Specify a drop off date:</label>
    <input id="dropoffdate" type="text" name="attributes[dropoffdate]" value="{{ product.attributes.dropoffdate }}" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="pickupdate">Specify a pick up date:</label>
    <input id="pickupdate" type="text" name="attributes[pickupdate]" value="{{ product.attributes.pickupdate }}" />
  </p>

</div>

<script>
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#dropoffdate").datepicker( { 
    minDate: +1, 
    maxDate: '+2M',
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  } );
});

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#pickupdate").datepicker( { 
    minDate: +1, 
    maxDate: '+2M',
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  } );
});
</script>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
$("#dropoffdate").datepicker({
  minDate: new Date() +1,
  maxDate: new Date() +60,
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  onClose: function() {
    $("#pickupdate").datepicker({
     ....
     minDate: new Date($("#dropoffDate").val()) + 1,
     maxDate: new Date($("#dropoffDate").val()) + 60,
  });

});
```